# Primefaces wizard partial submit

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.4.1 and JSF2.
Let's say I have a following template:

```
<p:wizard>
  <p:tab>
    <p:inputText value="#{myBean.value1}" />
    <p:inputText value="#{myBean.value2}" />
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab><ui:include src="some_content"/></p:tab>
</p:wizard>
```

When user click on next step, I would like to have:

- value1 automatically submited
- value2 should not be submited

How to achieve that? I tried to set immediate="true" on some input components, but they are always submited.

The problem is that I have more complicated template, where some components are not visible by default and it submits wrong values for those inputs. I can manually fix that, but I really need to prevent primefaces-wizard from updating those values automatically when I click next step.

Comment: if you dont want it to get submitted why 'inputText' ? why not outputText, if its conditional based you can use rendered property to shuffle between input and output perhaps.

Comment: I put "inputText" inside primefaces "inplace" component and it is submited twice - once when I finish editing with inplace, and then when i press next step.
I would like to skip second submit.